# Which coil configurations transfers the most magnetic flux?

Tags: electromagnetism, induction, electronics, electromagnetic-induction

So i'm working on a home project that involves magnetic coupling. I was wondering, of the two configurations described bellow, which one would should allow the secondary coil to receive the most magnetic flux from the primary coil? For both cases assume all other variables (such as number of turns) is the same for both configurations. Please excuse my crude drawings in advance haha.

Configuration 1
[image: Configuration 1]

You have a single iron core with two inductors on it (primary coil and secondary coil). The primary coil has AC current running through it and the secondary coil should have a current induced via magnetic induction.

Reasoning- Since iron has a larger relative permeability then air, the magnetic flux will travel throughout the iron core and into the secondary coil.

Configuration 2
[image: Configuration 2]

The primary coil is wrapped around a hollow plastic tube and has AC current running through it. The secondary coil is wrapped around a separate solid iron core. The secondary coil is then placed inside of the primary coil.

Reasoning- The magnetic field created by the primary coil  will be strongest in the center of the coil (Within the hollow tube). So by placing the secondary coil within the primary coil it will be exposed to the strongest portion of the magnetic field.

Comment: 1 is better than 2, because as you said iron is a conductor of flux.  Go with 3.  Short iron core and overlap the two coils.